# jQuery+JS computed selector

Tags: jquery-selectors

Sorry for the bad wording of the title, but here's my problem. Suppose I have a list where every item has a class:

```
<ol>
  <li class="chapter">Chapter 1</li>
  <li class="chapter">Chapter 2</li>
...
```

I want to select the item which is corresponding to make the user's current chapter, which is known by javascript, in bold. So if the user is on Chapter 2 I would do something like:

```
$(".chapter:eq(2)").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

But I can't do

```
$(".chapter:eq("+currentChapter+")").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

as it gives me Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm using a template to insert the variables but I have verified that `currentChapter` is in fact defined and the number I expect it to be.

```
function fetchContent(startSlide) {ldelim}
    var chapterSize    = {$chapterSize};
    var currentChapter = {$chapter};
    var chapterName    = "{$chapterName}";

    alert(typeof(currentChapter)); // number
    alert(currentChapter); //e.g. 3 works
    alert(currentChapter + "aaa"); //e.g. 3aaa
    $(".chapter:eq("+currentChapter+")").css("font-weight", "bold"); // doesn't work
```

Comment: What's `currentChapter`?

Comment: It's a number. (I have verified this by a function later on in the code)

Comment: It looks like it should work fine, provided `currentChapter` is defined: http://jsfiddle.net/S7WHk/

Comment: @pg-robban - It makes no difference whether it's a number, as it will be coerced to a String when you concatenate it with a String in the selector. Alert out the value of `currentChapter` on the line before the line with the problem. What does it say?

Comment: I agree with @James Allardice.  Do an alert on currentChapter (not its type) to make sure it's being set.

Comment: 3 if I'm on chapter 3 and so on. It gives me the number I expect.

Comment: You have to subtract 1 if your chapters are in order (eq is 0 based)

Comment: No need, my chapters do start on 0 (Preface/Forewords and so on). As I said, the numbers are what I expect them to be.

Comment: @pg-robban - Is the problematic line of code in that `fetchContent` function? If not, are you sure that function is being called before the problematic line is executed?

Comment: The line is inside that function, and the function is being called. Is that a problem? I can do for example `alert(currentChapter + "aaa")` which gives me 3aaa for chapter 3 for instance.

Comment: No not at all, I was just thinking that perhaps the line was outside of the function, in which case it would not have access to the `currentChapter` variable. I'm out of ideas... as you can see in the fiddle I posted, it seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach, fetch all elements and then select only the one you want (I know it's best to select your element right in the selector, but just to try it out).

```
$(".chapter").eq(currentChapter).css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Also, looking at your code, it seems like `currentChapter` is a local variable inside the `fetchContent` function. Are you sure you can access that variable when you are calling the jQuery function? Try to check the existence and value of the `currentChapter` variable right before calling the jQuery function which is causing you problems.

**EDIT**

From the jQuery documentation [jQuery :eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.

Comment: Your approach seems to be working. As for your question, see my updated code.

Comment: alert( typeof( currentChapter ) ); check the type of the variable, if it's not a string or a number it may be causeof problems. You could also try to force it to be a string like $(".chapter:eq(" + currentChapter.toString() + ")")

Comment: Try to store the string selector in a variable, then pass only that variable as the jQuery selector. var selector = ".chapter:eq(" + currentChapter + ")"; $(selector).css(...);

Comment: That seems to work too. I prefer the solution in your answer though.

Comment: It also appears to be the fastest way. Just edited my answer with the latest documentation about that selector.